# how to edit email body before sending using Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, smtp

I have generated email function, that sends email to multiple people using laravel.

Now I want to generate an edit window so that i can write the body of email,like in Gmail, if we are sending mail, we first edit body and hit send mail.

So, if anyone know how can I implement this, leave a comment.

Comment: I don't know how to implement it in laravel, but I'm gonna leave you a comment and tell you that your question is too Broad.

Comment: Make a form with 2 input text's. First input should be email subject and the second body of email. Then after "click" on button "send" you actually send that data from your controller to those people. That's how i would do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
    public function showForm(Request $request )
    {
        //Get Content From The Form
        $name = $request->input('name');
        $email = Input::get('agree');
        $message = $request->input('message');

        //Make a Data Array
        $data = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'message' => $message
        );

        //Convert the view into a string
        $emailView = View::make('contactemail')->with('data', $data);
        $contents = (string) $emailView;

        //Store the content on a file with .blad.php extension in the view/email folder
        $myfile = fopen("../resources/views/emails/email.blade.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $contents);
        fclose($myfile);

        //Use the create file as view for Mail function and send the email
        Mail::send('emails.email', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
            $message->to( $data['email'], 'Engage')->from('stifan@xyz.com')->subject('A Very Warm Welcome');
        });
//        return view();
    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('contactform', 'ClientsController@showForm');
Route::get('/', 'ClientsController@profile');
```

The view **contactemail** has the data to be sent, and the view **email** we are sending through mail function. When the user puts data in the form, that data will get saved in **email.blade.php** because of these lines of code:

```
//Convert the view into a string
        $emailView = View::make('contactemail')->with('data', $data);
        $contents = (string) $emailView;

        //Store the content on a file with .blad.php extension in the view/email folder
        $myfile = fopen("../resources/views/emails/email.blade.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $contents);
        fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be as simple as

```
Mail::send([], array('yourValue' => $yourValue), function($message) use ($yourValue) {
    $MailBody = 'Your Custom Body';
    $message->setBody($MailBody, 'text/html');
    $message->to('yourtoaddress@yourdomain.com');
    $message->subject('Your Custom Subject');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I am fairly new to Laravel myself, I could try to help you out with this. Firstly, set up your routes in the Routes.php file. For e.g.

```
Route::get('myapp/sendEmail', 'EmailController@returnComposeEmail');
Route::post('myapp/sendEmail', 'EmailController@sendEmail');
```

The first route when visited should return a view to the user where he can compose his email. This basically is a form which will be submitted by the `POST` method when the user clicks the 'Send' button. The second route is for that method which would collect the submitted data and use it appropriately then to send the email.

If you go by the routes I have provided, you should have a controller file named `EmailController.php` with the following methods:

```
public function returnComposeEmail()
{
return view('pages.ComposeEmail');
}
public function sendEmail(Request $input)
{
    $input = $input->all();
    $dataArray = array();
    $dataArray['emailBody'] = $input['emailBody'];
    $to = $input['to'];
    $subject = $input['subject'];
    Mail::send('email.body', ['dataArray' => $dataArray], function ($instance) use ($to, $subject)
        {
            $instance->from(env('MAIL_USERNAME'), 'Your Name Here');
            $instance->to($to, 'Recipient Name');
            $instance->subject($subject);
            $instance->replyTo(env('MAIL_REPLY_TO', 'some@email.id'), 'Desired Name');
        });
}
```

You may use use the `$dataArray` in the `email/body.blade.php` file as is or as per your requirement.

Do let me know if I could be of help. :-)